# Showing PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED while trying to connect with api for using docusign

Tags: php, codeigniter, docusignapi, e-signature

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught DocuSign\\eSign\\Client\\ApiException:
 Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code \[401\] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:
{s:9:"errorCode";s:29:"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED";s:7:
"message";s:95:"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. 
An Integrator key was not specified.";} 
in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\system\\vendor\\docusign\\esign-client\\src\\Client\\ApiClient.php:344 Stack trace: #0 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\system\\vendor\\docusign\\esign-client\\src\\Api\\EnvelopesApi.php(4606): DocuSign\\eSign\\Client\\ApiClient-\>callApi('/v2.1/accounts/...', 'POST', Array, '{"documents":\[{...', Array, '\\\\DocuSign\\\\eSign...', '/v2.1/accounts/...') #1 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\system\\vendor\\docusign\\esign-client\\src\\Api\\EnvelopesApi.php(4525): DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi-\>createEnvelopeWithHttpInfo('f2494a1d-3507-4...', Object(DocuSign\\eSign\\Model\\EnvelopeDefinition), NULL) #2 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\application\\controllers\\docusign.php(68): DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi-\>createEnvelope('f2494a1d-3507-4...', Object(DocuSign\\eSign\\Model\\EnvelopeDefinition)) #3 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\system\\core\\CodeIgniter.php(360): docusign-\>signdocument('2133') #4 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\index.php(202): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in **C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\affiniks_staging\\affiniks\\app\\system\\vendor\\docusign\\esign-client\\src\\Client\\ApiClient.php** on line **344**
```

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once (BASEPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');

use DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi;
use DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient;
use DocuSign\eSign\Configuration;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document;


class docusign extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load the DocuSign configuration and set the API credentials
        $config = new Configuration();
        $accessToken ='***********';
        $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", 
        json_encode([
        "Username" => "*****", // Replace with your DocuSign email
        "Password" => "*****", // Replace with your DocuSign password
        "IntegratorKey" => "******" // Replace with your Integrator Key
        ])
        );

        $config->setHost('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi');
        $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $accessToken);

      
       $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);

        // $config->setClientId('****'); // Your DocuSign client ID
        // $config->setClientSecret('******'); // Your DocuSign client secret

        
    }

    public function signdocument($userId) {
        // Load the document that corresponds to the user
        $documentPath = 'affiniks_doc.docx';

        // Create an envelope definition
        $envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
            'status' => 'sent',
            'documents' => [new Document([
                'document_base64' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($documentPath)),
                'name' => 'affiniks_doc.docx',
                'file_extension' => 'docx',
                'document_id' => '1',
            ])],
            'recipients' => [new Signer([
                'email' => '******', // User's email address
                'name' => '****',
                'recipient_id' => '1',
                'client_user_id' => $userId, // Unique identifier for the user
                'tabs' => [],
            ])],
        ]);

        $config = new Configuration();

        $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        // Create the envelope and get the signing URL
        $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $envelopeSummary = $envelopesApi->createEnvelope('*********', $envelopeDefinition);

        // Redirect the user to the DocuSign signing URL
        $redirectUrl = $envelopeSummary->getEnvelopeId();
        redirect($redirectUrl); // You may need to customize this redirection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to use basic authentication which is now deprecated. You'd need to modify your integration to use OAuth2.0 and authenticate with an access token.

Read the announcement [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/docusign-api-basic-user-password-authentication-retirement) for more info.