# Getting USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED with newly created integration key

Tags: docusignapi

In Demo account, I created a new integration key, and I keep getting authentication error when calling create envelope API using X-DocuSign-Authentication. It is working fine if I use the same credentials with any existing IK I have.

{
"errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
"message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing PARTNER\_AUTHENTICATION\_FAILED while trying to connect with api for using docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124616/showing-partner-authentication-failed-while-trying-to-connect-with-api-for-using)

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124616/showing-partner-authentication-failed-while-trying-to-connect-with-api-for-using/77124661#77124661). You are using basic authentication which has now been deprecated.

Comment: okay, so it is still supported for existing IK, but for new IK not supported anymore?

Comment: Correct. New applications are blocked from using basic authentication